# Unique JMenu for every column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jmenu

I'm trying to add a JMenu component for every column in my JTable. The tricky bit is that I'd like the menu to be unique for each column e.g. right clicking on a column header displays a menu which is unique for the column. Anyone has an idea of how to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. add a `MouseListener` to the table header
2. use the `columnAtPoint(...)` method of `JTableHeader` to get the column that was clicked
3. display your menu for the specific column

Comment: I think this is what I'm after. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The tools MouseListener, MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger() and MouseEvent.getPoint() give you all the information you need for the user actions.

Likewise JTable.getTableHeader()/getColumnModel(), JTableHeader/TableColumn give you all the information about the columns and header.

You just need to wire it up.